# Interface in Python

Tags: python, interface, menu

How do I create an interface with a function menu() in Python?
It is supposed to work with inputs.
I have already created the menu but do not know how to make an interface out of it.
P.S. I did not have enough time to change all names. It is about a queue and its methods that I have defined before in a class named Fila.

```
f = Fila()
def menu():
    print('---------- MENU PRINCIPAL ----------')
    print('0. Sair do menu')
    print('1. Início do atendimento')
    print('2. Clientes não prioritários')
    print('3. Clientes prioritários')
    print('4. Próximo cliente a ser atendido')
    print('5. Ver quem é o próximo cliente?')
    print('6. Quem abandonou a fila?')
    print('7. Fechar o atendimento')
    print('8. Quantas pessoas estão à espera?')
    print('9. Listar clientes à espera')
    print('10. Ficheiro com os clientes que não puderam ser atendidos hoje')
    print('11. Fila a começar com as pessoas que não foram atendidas ontem')
    print('-------------------------------------')
    value = input('Olá! O que deseja?')
    while str.isdigit(value) is False:
        print('-------------------------------------')
        print('Introduza um número do menu')
        value = input('Olá! O que deseja?')
    value = int(value)
    while value >= 12:
        print('-------------------------------------')
        print('Impossível abrir o menu')
        value = input('Tente mais tarde.')
        print('-------------------------------------')
        if str.isdigit(value):
            value = int(value)
        else:
            while str.isdigit(value) is False:
                print('Impossível abrir menu.')
                value = input('Tente mais tarde')
        value = int(value)
    value = int(value)
    while 0 < value < 12:
        if value == 1:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   INÍCIO DO ATENDIMENTO   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.__init__())
        elif value == 2:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   CLIENTES NÃO PRIORITÁRIOS   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            client = input('O seu nome completo, ID/Passaporte, secção e prioridade - False')
            print(f.insert_clients(client))
        elif value == 3:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   CLIENTES NÃO PRIORITÁRIOS   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            client = input('O seu nome completo, ID/Passaporte, secção e prioridade - True')
            print(f.insert_p_clients(client))
        elif value == 4:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   PRÓXIMO CLIENTE A SER ATENDIDO  ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.serve_client())
        elif value == 5:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   VER QUEM É O PRÓXIMO CLIENTE?  ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.view_next_client())
        elif value == 6:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   QUEM ABANDONOU A FILA?   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            index = input('Qual é a posição/index do cliente que deseja sair da fila?')
            print(f.abandon_queue(index))
        elif value == 7:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   FECHAR ATENDIMENTO   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.close())
        elif value == 8:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   QUANTAS PESSOAS ESTÃO À ESPERA?   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.__len__())
        elif value == 9:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   LISTAR CLIENTES À ESPERA   ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.__str__())
        elif value == 10:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   FICHEIRO COM OS CLIENTES QUE NÃO PUDERAM SER ATENDIDOS HOJE    ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.guardar_ficheiro())
        elif value == 11:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('   FILA A COMEÇAR COM AS PESSOAS QUE NÃO FORAM ATENDIDAS ONTEM    ')
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print(f.carregar_no_inicio())
        print('---------- MENU PRINCIPAL ----------')
        print('0. Leave')
        print('1. Beginning')
        print('2. Non Priority Client')
        print('3. Priority Client')
        print('4. Who is being answered')
        print('5. Who is the next client')
        print('6. Who abandoned the queue')
        print('7. Close shop')
        print('8. How many people are waiting')
        print('9. Clients info')
        print('10. File with clients')
        print('11. People that where not answered')
        print('-------------------------------------')
        value = input('Choose a number')
        while str.isdigit(value) is False:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('Choose a number')
            value = input('Hi')
        value = int(value)
        while value >= 12:
            print('-------------------------------------')
            print('Impossible')
            value = input('Try later')
            if str.isdigit(value):
                value = int(value)
            else:
                while str.isdigit(value) is False:
                    print('-------------------------------------')
                    print('Impossible.')
                    value = input('Try later')
            value = int(value)
        value = int(value)
    print('See you next time')
```

Comment: Could you edit and say more information and possible images or code snippets of what you've done already and what menu() you're talking about. With that you could easily get help with what you looking to do.

Comment: @Michael Amadi I have edited and I put the menu() code. Some names are not in english  because I do not have much time at the moment but the idea is to create an interface with that menu

Comment: Looks to me like you've done it - all you need to do now is call the ```menu```  function - ```menu()```

Comment: it is preferred to use `len(f)` instead of `f.__len__()`, and `str(f)` instead of `f.__str__()`. And `f.__init__()` doesn't look good. You should rather create function which `(re)set` all values - ie. `f.reset()`  and you could even run it inside `__init__` to set values at first start.

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem but you need only run `menu()` at the end of code.